# How to view a file's property in Xcode 4 (used to be command-I)

Tags: xcode, xcode4

In Xcode 3, I used to select a file, and press command-I to view the file's property. I frequently have files missing, and hence this will show me the path to the file to fix.

In Xcode 4, command-I no longer works. What can I do?

Comment: Sorry. Accidental double post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new shortcut is **Option-Command-1** to show the file inspector.

If the file is missing, you can click on the icon at Location section to re-reference the file.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could get to it now is select the file, right click, "Open in Finder", then command-I.

The other option is try to see if "File Inspector" in the Utilities sidebar would give you enough information.